# Let me know the logic the solve these kind of problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

One year ago, the ratio of Harsha's and Mandar's salaries was 3:5. The ratios of their individual salaries of last year and present year are 2:3 and 4:5 respectively. If their combined salary for the present year is Rs 86,000, find the present salary of Harsha

Comment: I hardly think this user's acceptance of one answer, which is NOT obligatory, will provide any more useful information for "future others" than without an accept.

Answer (score 1):

First off, try to write everything you know as an expression or equation.

Going in order through the problem I will let $H_1$ and $M_1$ be the salaries last year and $H_2$ and $M_2$ be the salaries this year:
$$\frac{H_1}{M_1}=\frac{3}{5}\Rightarrow5H_1=3M_1$$
$$3H_1 = 2H_2, 5M_1 = 4M_2$$
$$H_1 = \frac{2}{3}H_2, M_1 = \frac{4}{5}M_2$$
$$H_2+M_2=86000$$

So, ideally we would like a second equation to go with that last sum so we can have two equations for two unknowns.  Manipulating and substituting with the first two equations yields
$$5\times\frac{2}{3}H_2=3\times\frac{4}{5}M_2\Rightarrow\frac{10}{3}H_2=\frac{12}{5}M_2$$
Now you have two equations with two unknowns for their current salaries.
$$50H_2=36M_2$$
$$H_2+M_2=86000$$

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to start with is assigning some variables to the unknowns, and setting up some equations with the given information. Let $h_1,h_2$ be the last year's and present salaries for Harsha, respectively, and let $m_1,m_2$ be the same for Mandar. With the given information, we know:
$$\begin{cases}3h_1=5m_1\\2h_1=3h_2\\4m_1=5m_2\\m_2+h_2=86000\end{cases}$$
There are enough equations now to substitute, and rearrange to have an equation only involving $m_2$, which gives Mandar's present year's salary.

Answer (score 0):

Just retranscript the problem statement

1. $\dfrac{H_0}{M_0}=\dfrac35$
2. $\dfrac{H_0}{H_1}=\dfrac23,\dfrac{M_0}{M_1}=\dfrac45$
3. $H_1+M_1=86000$

This is a system of four equations in four unknowns, which can be put in a linear form.

For convenience, eliminate $H_0$ and $M_0$ with $$H_0=\frac23H_1,M_0=\frac45M_1$$ and the system becomes

$$\begin{cases}5\dfrac23H_1-3\dfrac45M_1=0,\\H_1+M_1=86000\end{cases}$$

which should raise no difficulty.

Comment: The ONLY thing that differs from turkeyhundt, is the re-subscripting. You've been around long enough to know better. And that answer was posted almost twenty minutes before yours.

Comment: @amWhy: I want to stress how to faithfully retranscript the problem statement, and then apply a resolution strategy. Let the OP appreciate.

Comment: Not an answer ${}{}{}{}{}$